# Comparator for sorting 2D arrays and 1D arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I used the following code for sorting a 2D array of int[][] type in **reverse order** by making use of a comparator.

```
int[][] arr = {{2,3},{3,5},{5,8}};
      
      Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b) -> Integer.compare(b[1], a[1]));
```

But I am unable to sort a 1D array of int[] type using similar approach. On the internet I found information saying "The only way to sort a primitive array in descending order is, first sort the array in ascending order and then reverse the array in place."

Why am I able to sort a 2D array of primitive type, but not a 1D array using comparator?

Comment: Where did you get that citation from? What code have you tried to sort a 1d array?

Comment: Is that answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966814/java-arrays-sort-method-takes-1d-arrays-but-i-can-pass-a-2d-array-as-well-the ?

Comment: It is possible to sort an `int[][]` in descending order because you basically compare `int[]`s against each others. And as per [JLS, §10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) "*Arrays are objects*".

Comment: `The direct superclass of an array type is Object` so you can use objects in comparator where 2D array is 1D array of 1D array/object but for 1D array you need to pass primitive in comparator which is not valid

Comment: And if you are complaining about why there is no build-in method for sorting array descending order, then write your own sort function for that, or you can do using stream api in one line https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673782/4207306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to sort an `int[][]` in descending order because one basically compares `int[]`s against each others. As per [JLS, §10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-10.html): "*... Arrays are objects ...*".

Looking closer at the [`Arrays` API, we find method `sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator)), which, together with some static builder methods from [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html), allows to reverse-sort an array of objects:

```
T[] someArray =  ...
Arrays.sort(someArray, Comparator.<T>naturalOrder().reversed())
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Wn9NZ4)

This only works for object-arrays, not for primitive arrays. And for primitive arrays, we do not have any method `sort(int[], Comparator<...>)` in `Arrays` (probably because one cannot use primitives as generic types, [project Valhalla](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/valhalla/sov/01-background.html) may or may not change this in the future).

So yes, sorting an array of primitives and then reversing it seems like the only option if one wants to have constant memory overhead. It would look something like this (sketch):

```
final int[] values = { 1, 5, 3, 2, 4 };
Arrays.sort(values);
reverse(values);
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WcJz1n)

Answer (score 2):

There just aren't any built-in sort methods that accept a 1D primitive array and a `Comparator`.

As for *why*, only the designers can say authoratively, but here are some arguments against having them:

- Primitive arrays are not used very often in Java programs to begin with.
- A `sort` implementation that uses `Comparator` would need to wrap every array element in an object to pass them to the `Comparator` anyway, so you might as well have the user convert the array of `int` into an array of `Integer` themselves.
- You would need to add 7 or 14 more [`Arrays.sort` implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) which is a non-trivial amount of code to test
- The most common use case for a custom comparator is sorting in reverse, and you can already achieve that by first sorting and then reversing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stream` to convert an `int` to an `Integer`, do sort using a `Comparator` and reconvert it to an `int[]`.

```
final int[] values = {2, 0, 5, 1, 3, 4};
int[] reversed = IntStream.of(values)
    .boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .mapToInt(i -> i)
    .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reversed));
```

output:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `.mapToInt(i -> i)` can be replaced with `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` =)

Comment: Depending on the reader, it may be more readable =) (stream-operations tend to favor method references over lambda expressions)

Comment: As an aside: I would mention that this approach has `O(n)` memory overhead since `n` `Integer`-objects and one additional `int[]` of length `n` are created.